# Twilio - How to dial two/multiple numbers and join them to conference using TwiML Bin or other method

Tags: twilio

I would like to set up Twilio number so that when dialed, it will dial two other phone numbers and when answered join a conference.

The following TwiML Bin will call two numbers and join conference, however only the first number of the two numbers will join and the second stops ringing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Dial record="true">
    <Number>XXX-XXX-XXXX</Number>
    <Number>XXX-XXX-XXXX</Number>
    <Conference>My conference</Conference>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

Any way to make both phone numbers ring until answered and join the conference?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the REST API to place two outbound calls and add them to the conference. You can do that either using the [Calls resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource) or conference participants resource ([Create a Participant](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/conference-participant-resource#create-a-participant))